# 2 simple and quick C# specific Visual Studio questions?

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

Just a quick one really, I've tried googling and searching through the visual studio tools but I seem to be having no luck, so I know I'll get a quick answer on here!

I've been developing in vb.net for a while using visual studio and just moved back to c# and I'm irritated by a few things that I'm sure just need a check box ticking or unticking somewhere.

**Firstly**, when I created an event in C# I have to write out the event and then add it to the markup code, in vb I used to be able to select the control from the top left drop down (when in code behind) and then select the event from the top right dropdown, this would automatically create the event for me and attach it to the control. I can't find the setting for this to be turned on!

**Secondly**, when I create classes in a sub folder, the namespace for that class is given the folder name as a sub namespace. I just want it to use the namespace of the project by default, it's just getting a bit annoying!

E.G.

MyProject has MyProject namespace

MyProject --> MyFolder --> MyClass has the name space MyProject.MyFolder ....

Sorry for the outrageously basic question.

Regards

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1) C# and VB handle event handler subscriptions quite differently so there is no direct equivilent of this in C#. You can do this by switching to the events tab of the properties window, and double clicking on the event you want to handle (in design view). From code view, simply type *"myControl.EventIWantToHandle +="* and then double hit *tab*, which will generate the event handler method for you. The best place to do this is most likely in the constructor, right below the InitializeComponent call.

2) Highlight the folder in solution explorer, and in the properties window set the 'NamespaceProvider' property to *false**

*It's actually a Best Practice™ for the folder stucture to match the namespace stucture - C# is helping you out by doing this (I'm a little surprised that VB doesn't)

Comment: I just find it irritating when I access my business logic and have to have using MyBusinessLogic.Management, MyBusinessLogic.EventSystem, MyBusinessLogic.ECommerce, MyBusinessLogic.Article etc. I just want to add MyBusinessLogic then call my manager classes in the code. I can see how it comes in handy in very large projects but I think I've split my projects up in to appropriately sized tiers so don't need it.

Comment: @ThePower this would indicate one of two potential issues with the way you have seperated your project out. It may be that your namespaces are too granular and could be merged together, or it may be that you have too many cross-namespace references. Then again, it could just be that you need to write a facade interface over your entire business tier.

Comment: I disagree on point #1...the IDE could just as easily generate the event code for you from the code view in C# as it does in VB.  Obviously the generated code would differ slightly due to language syntax.

Comment: @tcarvin I see your point but it wouldn't be quite that easy, since the code view window would need to modify the designer generated file (which is owned by the designer view). Having two views modifying the generated code presents a problem. In VB this isn't an issue as the event handler subscription lives in the very same code file (not in the generated code).

Comment: The IDE, for C#, drops code into both the user and designer file when you use the Properties editor and access the events.  I think MS could figure out how to invoke the exact same functionality from a different window :)  I suspect it is just MS trying to give each language its own "flavor"

Answer (score 0):

1. This isn't available in C#.  If you want to add the event, you can do so from the designer.  First select the control, view the events of the control in the Properties dialog, and then double-click the event name to create the code-behind.
2. This is by design.  Folders are intrinsically treated as hierarchies in your namespace.

Sorry you're frustrated, but believe me there are many advantages to learning C# over VB.NET.

Comment: I'm originally a C# man, so was used to doing this stuff before, but had to move to vb.net for a while (because of my job), but now I'm back on board and was used to the time consumption (the first point mainly) so wondered if it was possible. Obviously not :-(

Comment: "Sorry you're frustrated, but believe me there are many advantages to learning C# over VB.NET." ... I'd say there is just one and it is a slightly higher job market value.  Otherwise they are close enough to code in what you prefer better.

Comment: You're right.  The differences are marginal and shrinking with very release.  The market value is the #1 advantage that I was thinking of.  I would also argue that C# is more akin to JavaScript and functional programming so learning C# will give you a leg up in that area.